# MYSQL delete - Table 'USER_TABLE' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am new to MySql large queries, and trying to find some solution for my problem,

I looking for delete duplicate values based on **"ID_object"** column in my **USER_TABLE**.

Here is my USER_TABLE description,

```
`USER_TABLE` (
  `ID` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `ID_OBJECT` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSERTION_TIME` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `USER_TABLE_inx01` (`ID`(255)),
  KEY `user_inx02` (`ID_OBJECT`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I tried the following query to remove the duplicate ID_OBJECTs,

```
delete from USER_TABLE  where id in (
select ID from USER_TABLE,
(select ID_OBJECT, min(INSERTION_TIME) as fecha from USER_TABLE group by ID_OBJECT having count(ID_OBJECT)>1) tbpr 
where USER_TABLE.ID_OBJECT = tbpr.ID_OBJECT and USER_TABLE.INSERTION_TIME=tbpr.fecha);
```

But it says, 
 `SQL Error (1093): Table 'USER_TABLE' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data`

Can anyone assist me in this?

Comment: I think the problem is you can't delete rows at the same time as trying to read them. Maybe populating a temporary table containing the duplicate IDs and then using that as the source of IDs to delete would be the solution.

Comment: @ADyson, Thank you for your comment, Can you please make an answer for this with small sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it. I haven't attempted to check whether your actual business logic for removing duplicates is correct, since your stated requirement isn't 100% clear anyway, but this is one way you can overcome the error message:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS duplicates AS (
SELECT UT.id 
FROM `USER_TABLE` AS UT
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
    ID_OBJECT, 
    MIN(INSERTION_TIME) AS fecha 
  FROM `USER_TABLE` 
  GROUP BY ID_OBJECT 
  HAVING COUNT(ID_OBJECT)>1) AS tbpr 
ON
  UT.ID_OBJECT = tbpr.ID_OBJECT AND UT.INSERTION_TIME = tbpr.fecha
);

DELETE FROM `USER_TABLE`
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM duplicates);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS duplicates;
```

You can see a working demo here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/amnAPUftLD1SmW67fjVSEv/0

Comment: For me, the syntax of the first statement above was slightly incorrect (I had to remove `AS`), so the first line read `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS duplicates (`

Comment: @GuyPaddock what was that exactly? Did you get a specific syntax error? This code seems to execute ok on all recent versions of MySQL, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your query slightly

```
delete from USER_TABLE  
where concat(id_object,insertion_time) in 
(
select concat(ID_object,fecha) from
(
select ID_OBJECT, min(INSERTION_TIME) as fecha 
from USER_TABLE 
group by ID_OBJECT 
having count(ID_OBJECT)>1
) tbpr 
)
```

But this would not cope with triplicates, quadruplets etc. so maybe you need to reverse the logic and keep only the max where there are multiples

```
delete from USER_TABLE  
where concat(id_object,insertion_time) not in 
(
select concat(ID_object,fecha) from
(
select ID_OBJECT, max(INSERTION_TIME) as fecha 
from USER_TABLE 
group by ID_OBJECT 
having count(ID_OBJECT)>1
) tbpr 
) 
and
id_object not in
(
select ID_object from
(
select ID_OBJECT, count(*) as fecha 
from USER_TABLE 
group by ID_OBJECT 
having count(ID_OBJECT) = 1
) tbpr2 
)
;

create table `USER_TABLE` (
  `ID` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `ID_OBJECT` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSERTION_TIME` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `USER_TABLE_inx01` (`ID`(255)),
  KEY `user_inx02` (`ID_OBJECT`(255))
) ;
truncate table user_table;
insert into user_table values
(1,1,'2017-01-01'),(2,1,'2017-01-02'),(3,1,'2017-01-03'),
(4,2,'2017-01-01');
```

Result of first query

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from user_table;
+----+-----------+----------------+
| ID | ID_OBJECT | INSERTION_TIME |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 2  | 1         | 2017-01-02     |
| 3  | 1         | 2017-01-03     |
| 4  | 2         | 2017-01-01     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Result of second query

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from user_table;
+----+-----------+----------------+
| ID | ID_OBJECT | INSERTION_TIME |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 3  | 1         | 2017-01-03     |
| 4  | 2         | 2017-01-01     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```